# Exercise from Pugh's Real Analysis Regarding Zero Derivative on Open Subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Assume that $U$ is a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable everywhere on $U$. If $(Df)_p=0$ for all $p\in U$, show that $f$ is constant.

I immediately thought that this would be equal to showing that if $\text{grad}(f)$ is $0$ everywhere on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $f$ is constant on that subset, thus enabling us to use the generalized MVT: for any $[a,b]$ contained in $U$ we have $|f(p)-f(q)|\le\max\{\text{grad}(f)\}|p-q|$, and since $\text{grad}(f)=0$ everywhere on $U$, we get $f(p)=f(q)$ for all $p,q\in U$. Is this sufficient?

Pugh remarks that "the enjoyable open and closed argument is left to you as Exercise 20", suggesting that more is required. :\

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How do you prove that generalized MVT? Any requirement on the shape of your open set $U$?

Comment: I think people here already forgotten when initiated in Calculus and had doubts, consider such questions as silly and qualify negative, I do not like. I'm giving a upvote to counteract

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez : Don't need to over-interpret the down-vote..... It seems again that all the questions posted recently are down-voted.

Comment: time ago, one guy enter to my profile and given downvote in all my questions, answers

Comment: I don't know if this will work but it would be my first try: Fix $x_0\in U$ and define $A:=\{x\in U: f(x)=f(x_0)\}$. Then show $A$ is both open and closed in $U$. Since $U$ is connected we would have $A=U$ and $f$ would be constant on $U$. Verifying it is closed is straightforward.

Comment: Proving the theorem for any $[a,b]$ contained in $U$ is not sufficient ($U$ is not necessarily convex). Use the fact that a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is polygonally connected. Pugh's hint is _another_ approach (see @PtF's comment) that uses the fact that a non empty open and closed subset of a connected set coincides necessarily with the set.